# Set attributes of costum component via props [react native]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

First of all I am fairly new with React-Native. I am trying to create a reusable Custom InputGroup which you can set the attributes via props, but I'm not sure if it is really possible.

An attribute in this would be like `textContentType="password"`, I tried to do it with the standard `textContentType={this.props.textContentType}`, but that doesn't seem to work. It has something to do with the double quotes I guess.

My classes:

(Parent)

```
class RegisterForm extends React.Component {


    render() {
        // Load translations
        this.translationInitializer();

        if (this.state.isLoaded) {
            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Form>
                        <CustomInputGroup label={TranslationAction.translate('KEY.First Name')}
                                          textContentType={'givenName'}
                                          autoCompleteType={'name'} autoCapitalize={'words'}
                                          textInputChange={this.setFirstName}/>
                        <CustomInputGroup label={TranslationAction.translate('KEY.Last Name')}
                                          textContentType={'givenName'}
                                          autoCompleteType={'name'} autoCapitalize={'words'}
                                          textInputChange={this.setLastName}/>
                        <CustomInputGroup label={TranslationAction.translate('KEY.Email')}
                                          textContentType={'emailAddress'}
                                          autoCompleteType={'email'} autoCapitalize={'none'}
                                          textInputChange={this.setEmail}/>
                        <CustomInputGroup label={TranslationAction.translate('KEY.Mobile phone')}
                                          textContentType={'telephoneNumber'}
                                          autoCompleteType={'tel'} autoCapitalize={'none'}
                                          textInputChange={this.setPhoneNumber}/>
                        <CustomInputGroup label={TranslationAction.translate('KEY.Password')}
                                          textContentType={'password'}
                                          autoCompleteType={'password'} autoCapitalize={'none'}
                                          secureTextEntry={true} textInputChange={this.setPassword}/>
                    </Form>
                    {this.props.children}
                    <Button block onPress={() => UserAction.registerSubmit(this.props.navigation, this.state)}>
                        <Text>{TranslationAction.translate('KEY.Confirm registration')}</Text>
                    </Button>

                </View>
            );
        } else {
            return <View/>;
        }
    }
}

export default RegisterForm;
```

(Custom child component)

```
'use strict';

import {Input, InputGroup, Label, View} from "native-base";
import React from "react";


class CustomInputGroup extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <InputGroup>
                    <Label>{this.props.label}</Label>
                    <Input
                        textContentType={this.props.textContentType}
                        autoCompleteType={this.props.name}
                        autoCapitalize={this.props.autoCapitalize}
                        onChangeText={(e) => this.props.textInputChange(e)}
                        secureTextEntry={this.state.secureTextEntry}
                    />
                </InputGroup>
            </View>
        );
    }

}

export default CustomInputGroup;
```

Is there a neat way of solving this issue?

Comment: Any error that you are getting ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan no errors, but I've tested it with a visual attribute <Icon name={this.props.iconName} /> and it stays blank.

Comment: Any reason for using native-base ?, i tried with icons and it works fine

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan It's the UI library the company uses to create apps, but they also just started working with React-Native. Thanks for testing it, I'll give it another try myself